# Why do we "play" an instrument rather than "work" an instrument?

Tags: terminology

There's a line in the Steely Dan song **Deacon Blues** that mentions "working" a saxophone rather than "playing" one. But why *do* we say "play" rather than "work"? Is it just something that we've all got used to and don't think about it any more? Or is there a good reason?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about linguistics rather than musical practice. Yes, it's about a term *for* a musical practice, but it's not specialized musical jargon; the question is about the evolution of language. Note, languages differ. French uses *jouer*, the same word as to "play" a game, but Spanish uses *tocar*, the same as "to touch" (I think Italian is similar).

Comment: Also, did you try https://www.etymonline.com/word/play? It seems, from OE times at least, it was making a point about fluency and facility.

Comment: Well, why do we say "write a book" and not "work a book"? Why do we say "cook some food" rather than "work some food"? Why do we say "ride a bike" rather than "work a bike"? Why do we say "answer a question" rather than "work a question"?

Comment: With musical terms like toccata, sonata, ricercare, etc. etc. should we really close a question that looks to connect a particular word to music theory usage?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis The way I see it, "What does 'fugue' mean" is on-topic. For "Why do we use the word 'fugue,'" the answer is "well, you see, *fuga* means "flee," as in a chase, and the imitative parts are chasing after each other etc etc" is an etymology question. Very on-topic on English Language and Usage SE (if the poster shows that they've looked it up and how their research fails to answer their question); it wouldn't be off-topic there just because the word is musical. I don't see a musical application to this question.

Comment: I think it's as much a neuroscience question as it is linguistics.

Comment: To expand what I found at etymonline: It seems, from way back in Old English, that "play" had some of the same meanings it does now: child's play, play an instrument, but also a sense of rapid, easy movement, as in "the light *played* across the water," and it was this that led to both the "child's play" and "play an instrument" meanings.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a language, rather than music, question. I think it's all about *idiom* and *connotation*.

I don't know the Steely Dan song, but using the word "work" in a "blues" context certainly makes sense to connote "working class" or other low brow versus high brow ideas associated with the blues.

"Playing" an instrument is an idiomatic usage, it's just the particular verb chosen in English. You could say "operate" an instrument. It would sound strange, unidiomatic, but the meaning would be understood. Compare this to something like "suonare" in Italian. That is the idiomatic word for playing an instrument, but its broader meaning is "to sound." More literally translated into English you might say "sound the saxophone."

A personal anecdote: one time I was talking to a friend who was an English professor and who I would sometimes jam with (he sang, I operated the guitar.) The conversation got onto the word "play" and music. I suggested that the word "play" connotated children's play and a sense of exploration and "no rules", or at least rules you can change at will, like "Calvinball." Music, while usually following style conventions, is less like a strict recipe or work procedure, and is more like an exploration of the "infinite variety of music" (that's a Leonard Bernstein quote.) Music really flowers when you freely explore - "play" - with the possibilities.

If this wiki page is correct, the etymology of "[play](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/play)" includes meanings "move" and "exercise", which make sense when applied to a musical instrument. The historic meaning of the word isn't so much about games but instead about *movement.*

Comment: 'I operated the guitar' - I like it! Used to be in a band where we had a 'bass guitar holder'.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know the origin of the use of “play” but it predates any of our existences in this world. I also think most would agree that it is very difficult to think of any other word that we would naturally use to describe the act of getting sound from an instrument. The word “work” is really not associated with the act of playing a musical instrument. Perhaps “play” is used to encourage people to learn music by making it sound fun and not like a job. However the word “play” is not used in all languages. In Spanish it is “tocar”, meaning “to touch”. Italian it is “suonare”, loosely “to make sound”. In other languages it may the the specific act that determines the name of the act, such as blow, pluck or strike.

In the case of “Deacon Blues” it is a lyrical choice. If you look to the following line he says “I play just what I feel”. It would have been less poetic and bit awkward to use “play” instead of “work” in the first line so Fagen made an artistic choice in picking the word “work”. He learns to work the saxophone and plays what he feels. Interesting choice since learning how to play a musical instrument can feel like work but actually playing it can be very fun.

Answer (score 0):

Deacon Blues was written by Walter Becker and Donald Fagen in 1976.
The protagonist in the song was a sort of loser anti-hero who dreamed of being a jazz musician.

When writing songs, certain words either fit with the flow and the writer's ear and vision, or they don't.  "Play" the saxophone didn't work for Donald and Walter, nor did "blow" the saxophone. But "work" seemed right.

And considering how the odd mechanisms on a saxophone appear to function (to the admittedly accomplished pianists, bass players, and guitar players that Donald and Walter were) in such a complicated fashion, it seems as though learning to "work" a saxophone would be a daunting task.

"Working it" has since become a popular enough expression for encouraging a player of any instrument to go for it, and to keep doing something really good that they are onto.

A guy or gal rolls into an earnest and tasty solo, and band-mates are known to exclaim, "Work it, yeah boy, work it!".

Comment: This seems to answer the opposite question to the one that was asked, "why'd he say 'work'" rather than "how did we come to say 'play.'" Though the question you answered was *maybe* a better fit for this site.